# Masonry not working with jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-masonry

jQuery Masonry is not working with jQuery but working with javascript. Can you tell me why?

When I giving this code:

```
console.log(typeof $.masonry)
```

Showing "undefined"

But if I giving this code :

```
console.log(Masonry)
```

Showing:

```
function n(){y.apply(this,arguments)}
```

Comment: also tried with: console.log(typeof jQuery.masonry)

Answer (score 0):

Wihtout passing the right arguments or in this case selector it won't show the actualy type (because the actuall selector is missing)
Try it with

```
typeof $('selector').masonry
```

Comment: But how can I determine masonry is available?